# For which values of $p$ does there exist a holomorphic function $g$ such that $\frac{\text{sin}\ z}{z^p} = g^\prime(z)$ holds?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

For a positive integer $p$, consider the holomorphic  function  $f(z) = \frac{\text{sin}\ z}{z^p}$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.  For which values of $p$ does there exist a holomorphic function $g: \mathbb{C} \setminus\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z) = g^\prime(z)$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

My attempt:  I have written $\frac{\text{sin}\ z}{z^p} = \frac{1}{z^p} \Big(z - \frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^5}{5!} - ... \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} + ...\Big) = z^{1-p} - \frac{z^{3-p}}{3!} + \frac{z^{5-p}}{5!} - \cdots$

Now I have no idea how to proceed further. Please give me some hint. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: holomorphic functions admit primitives on simply connected (or more simply, convex) domains.

Comment: @Albert But $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is not simply connected...

Comment: Its easy to see by writing the primitve down that $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty c_nz^n$ has a primitive in the punctured plane if and only if $c_{-1}=0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Can I say that $p$ is in the set of all odd integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complex function $f: G\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ can be written as $f = g'$ for a holomorphic function $g$ if and only if $$\int\limits_\gamma f(z) dz = 0$$ for all closed curves $\gamma : [a,b]\rightarrow G$.

Taking loops around the origin, this integral vanishes exactly if the coefficient $a_{-1}$ of the Laurent series of $f$ is zero. This happens in your case, if there is no $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $(2n-1)-p = -1$, i.e. $2n \neq p$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,  which just means that $p\in(0,\infty)\setminus\{2,4,6,...\}$.